# How do I add an integer that does not already exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table A with column INCREMENT_NUMBER. We will say that there are five rows.

```
1
2
3
4
4
```

If a user adds a new row to table A, the INCREMENT_NUMBER column of that row should be 5. (It could be anything, as long as it isn't a number 1-4.) Keep in mind

```
INCREMENT_NUMBER integer auto_increment primary key
```

will not work because I need to allow for duplicates in the table and I don't think

```
insert
```

Comment: Why not just put a "no duplicate" ("unique") constraint on the column?

Comment: This question has some code smell to me.  What are you actually trying to *do*?

Comment: @ypercube Sorry. That should have been in my question. I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @Joe,  If there is no way to do this in mssql, that will be my next question.  To be honest, I was mostly curious if this was something that sql could do.

Comment: I still don't know what your goal is.  Do you want a key, or a non-unique value?  What determines whether the next value should be a new (unique to the table) value or not?

Comment: The idea was to emulate ypercube's answer. (But in MSSQL) If the system specified a number, that number would be entered, (and would probably be a duplicate).  If the system did not specify a number it would be unique.

Comment: Now, out of curiousity, why do you need this? It looks at least strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to allow duplicates, don't declare it as a `PRIMARY KEY` (and neither put a `UNIQUE` constraint on it).

In **MySQL** an `AUTO_INCREMENT` is allowed to have duplicates in that case - you just have to add a simple index on it:

```
CREATE TABLE test
( increment_number INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, INDEX inc_index (increment_number)
) ;

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(4);
```

Test in SQL-Fiddle: [test-1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31d26/1)

```
INSERT INTO test
VALUES
(NULL);

SELECT *
FROM test ;
```

Results in:

```
increment_number
----------------
1
2
3
4
4
5
```

---

In **SQL-Server**, you'll have to toggle the `IDENTITY_INSERT` setting `ON` and `OFF` to have similar behaviour:

```
CREATE TABLE test
( increment_number INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
, name varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test ON ;

INSERT INTO test (increment_number, name)
VALUES 
(1, 'Alex'),
(2, 'Bill'),
(3, 'Cathy'),
(4, 'Diana'),
(4, 'Dean');
```

And then [test-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92b72/1):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test OFF ;

INSERT INTO test (name)
VALUES
('Elaine') ;

SELECT *
FROM test ;
```

Results in:

```
increment_number  |  name
---------------------------
1                    Alex
2                    Bill
3                    Cathy
4                    Diana
4                    Dean
5                    Elaine
```

Comment: So in mysql, you can add an AUTO_INCREMENT constraint that will only increment when a user DOES NOT specify the number?  How about other databases?

Comment: @Holtorf: Exactly. I don't think this (the duplicates) is possible in SQL-Server with `IDENTITY`.

Comment: That sounds super obnoxious, but at least I know it is possible.  Thanks!